# How to compile contracts independently with Hardhat?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, compilation

I'm facing the following error, when compiling my contracts in Hardhat:

```
Warning: Contract code size exceeds 24576 bytes (a limit introduced in Spurious Dragon). This contract may not be deployable on mainnet. Consider enabling the optimizer (with a low "runs" value!), turning off revert strings, or using libraries.
```

1. I have the `optimizer: {enabled: true, runs: N}`, and already tested
   different values for `runs: N`.
2. I have also created libraries to
   reuse as much code as possible, and have followed [this
   suggestions](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/downsizing-contracts-to-fight-the-contract-size-limit/).

None of above worked for me (too much code). So, I have split my code in 3 different contracts that can be deployed independently (with a simple custom *deploy.ts script*).
The problem is that Hardhat is always compiling all the code under `/contracts` folder altogether, so I always getting the same error of `Contract code size exceeds 24576 bytes`

I have read the [Hardhat compilation documentation](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/compile-contracts) in order to find any configuration to compile independently, but nothing stated about this topic.

I have also read the [Hardhat documentation about path configuration](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config#path-configuration) but it seems that you can only to select one folder to compile all `.sol` inside, based on the text:

> sources: The directory where your contract are stored. This path is resolved from the project's root. Default value: './contracts'.

So, after doing my own research:

1. Does anyone know if it is possible (and how) to compile contracts
   independently (grouped in different folders) with Hardhat?
2. Do I need to create different Hardhat projects for the different
   contract groups?

Comment: I don't think Hardhat gives this warning for all contracts combined when it says contract size exceeding, it means one single contract is independently exceeding the size. because if the case you mentioned was true, then we will always get that error, but we don't.

Comment: As @ZartajAfser commented the error is not about the combined size of the contracts but about a single contract. One of your contracts is still too big.

Comment: But if I split the big contract in 2 new contracts, they will have dependencies with each other, so they will be treated as one by the compile, getting the same error.

The only option I see, is to deploy independently the contracts (with public functions), making one contract the owner of the other one. But does not seem the best approach for security concerns.

Comment: You have to make your contract(app) modular, like [diamond pattern](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535), but you can omit upgradability for example if you want.

Comment: Yes, I finally came across to this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow unlimited contract sizes in your hardhat config file.

```typescript
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
    },
    localhost: {
      chainId: 31337,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
    },
  },
  ...
};
```

Comment: This is useful and related to op's use case but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

After some research & testing, I see that the **warning comes from independent contracts**, taking into account that if .sol file's contract inherits other contracts, the total size will be sum of all involved contracts.

So, in conclusion, if this error comes from a contract, there are only 2 main approach to reduce the size.

1. Using libraries
2. Splitting the contract into independent contracts
3. [Optimize the code](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/downsizing-contracts-to-fight-the-contract-size-limit/)

If previous actions are not possible to reduce the size, refactoring to [Diamond pattern](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535) along with [Appstorage](https://dev.to/mudgen/appstorage-pattern-for-state-variables-in-solidity-3lki), or similar approach,  is the only solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer op's question.